# Is there any better way to achieve this hovering effect

Tags: html, css

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

button {
  margin: 0.3rem;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: transparent;
}

#last-btn {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

#first-btn:hover+#last-btn {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: black;
}



button:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" />

<button id="first-btn"><i class="fa fa-list"></i></button>
<button id="last-btn"><i class="fa-solid fa-grip-vertical"></i></button>
```

I am here to ask if there are any better to achieve this hovering effect between any two elements only using css without any 3rd party framework? Any suggestions would be great help! This seems good too but would be appreciated if any short method is there.

**I want last-btn to be of background black on screen loaded without changing with hover class, plz run the below file once to see the example**

Comment: why you just don't have a single rule for the button and another one for the button:hover? those 2 rules would be enough.

Comment: @DiegoD I want the last button to have that background without hovering and while hovering around first btn remove background color from last button? Can it be done using single rule?

Comment: so you basically want one default selection and other ones on hover should be selected. Also, why does the single rule matter?

Comment: Learn to not edit questions after looking at answers, then blaming the person who answered.

Comment: Dude, you literally edited your question after looking at mine. You had 4 extra lines of code, and when you saw it you edited. Stack Overflow has features to view edits. And, this is the only possible method using pure CSS. It would be better if you appreciate the efforts taken by developers, rather than updating your question after their answer and then again asking for better answers.

Comment: @TheMyth sorry for the inconvenience mate, I just looked back at my css and saw why should I need the line, I literally didn't edited after seeing one's answer and was searching for answer as given by Diego guy once again sorry for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a game where the less css rules is better, I think another strategy could be to have the two rules for `button` and `button:hover` in place and only one extra rule that will set the style of the `#last-btn`, only if no button are on `:hover`.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

button {
  margin: 0.3rem;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: transparent;
}

button:hover,
button:not(:hover)+#last-btn{
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" />

<button id="first-btn"><i class="fa fa-list"></i></button>
<button id="last-btn"><i class="fa-solid fa-grip-vertical"></i></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess its better to do this without define, which is the first or the last one. Less code and more flexibility.

With the active class you can mark the active one.

I know you search for less code but with buttons, i guess this is the shortest without change your style part.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

button {
  margin: 0.3rem;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: transparent
}

button:hover+button {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: black
}

button:hover, .active {
  background-color: black;
  color: white
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" />

<button><i class="fa fa-list"></i></button>
<button class="active"><i class="fa-solid fa-grip-vertical"></i>
```

Comment: But I don't see any difference else then you changed the id to classes, this first and last button are actually used for javascript so I need it there too

Comment: I changed #first-btn:hover+#last-btn to the button tag to make it unnessercery where the id is, you can take the active button with javascript to, document.getEelementsByClassName("active")[0]...

Answer (score 0):

As a relative newbie to all this I'd keep it simple as possible. If you have different buttons doing different things, then you do need to separate them.

I'd just do
#first-button {background-color: green;}
#first-button:hover {background-color: blue;}

#last-button {background-color: yellow;}
#last-button:hover {background-color: red;}

I'm a newbie but I think typing more and just separating things out makes it clearer and easier to play around with the single elements individually.

Of course if you can combine, then I would.

Additional advice: I found out :hover doesn't really work on touchscreen anyway and possibly not on Safari (?) so if you want something else to happen when the person CLICKS on the button too, you need to include #first-button:active as well as :hover for it to do anything.

This is my first ever answer so hopefully it is OK..

Answer (score -1):

Here's my go:

```css
button{
    margin: 0.3rem;
    text-align:center;
    border: none;   
    font-size: 1.2rem; 
    padding: 1rem;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    /* Just a few nice things */
    cursor: pointer; 
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
.button-holder button:hover{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;  
}
.button-holder #first-btn:hover + #last-btn{
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}
#last-btn{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;  
}
```

```html
<div class="button-holder">
  <button id="first-btn">Button 1</button>
  <button id="last-btn">Button 2</button>
 </div>
```

Comment: I want like button 2 to get that background color without hovering and remove it while hovering over button 1,you got my whole question in wrong way

Comment: I don't see difference between your and mine css, I asked for any short method of available

Comment: Dude, you literally edited your question after looking at mine. You had 4 extra lines of code, and when you saw it you edited. Stack Overflow has features to view edits. And, this is the only possible method using pure CSS. It would be better if you appreciate the efforts taken by developers, rather than updating your question after their answer and then again asking for better answers.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is not clear enough, but let's try to help.

I think your question is how to shorten this code you have, and not how to accomplish something else,

So we can just combine some selectors and go on.

```css
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    button {
      margin: 0.3rem;
      text-align: center;
      border: none;
      font-size: 1.2rem;
      padding: 1rem;
      border-radius: 15px;
      background-color: transparent;
    }

    #last-btn, #first-btn:hover {
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
    }

    #first-btn:hover+#last-btn {
      background-color: transparent;
      color: black;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" />

<button id="first-btn"><i class="fa fa-list"></i></button>
<button id="last-btn"><i class="fa-solid fa-grip-vertical"></i></button>
```

Here I just said that the `first-btn` and the hover status of the `last-btn` are the same style, then I said that when I hover over the last button let's set the first button again.

I think that's what you want.